# Gilab CICD pipeline - run the dev stage manually on all branches except main

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have 4 stages in my gilab cicd pipeline -

stages:

- dev-deploy
- test-deploy
- approval
- prod-deploy

there are 4 jobs inside the stage dev-deploy

I want to run the dev-deploy stage alone for all branch except `main` (which also the default branch).

The rule I have for all 4 jobs inside the stage dev-deploy is :

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: manual
      allow_failure: false
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
```

So on every push to any branch except `main` - I should be able to create a pipeline which shows only the dev-deploy stage and not the other stages and it should be MANUAL.

The above rule works fine only for the first time I push a change from my local branch to the remote branch.

for example, I create a branch on my local "`x/foo`" commit some changes and push to the remote for the first time then the pipeline is created and I can see the `dev-deploy stage` in the new pipeline created. But if I make additional commits to the same branch and push again I do not see a new pipeline with the dev-deploy stage in it.

I do not want to run the dev-deploy on any sort of MRs.

complete flow :

```
dev-deploy-common:
  stage: dev-deploy
  script:
    - cd ./aws_code_base/platform/CommonLib/
    - python setup.py setopt --command=options.package_data --option=CommonLib --set-value=devConfigs.json
    - python setup.py sdist
  artifacts:
    name: dev-commonlib
    paths:
      - aws_code_base/platform/CommonLib/dist/*tar.gz
    expire_in: 1 day
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: manual
      allow_failure: false
      changes:
        - aws_code_base/platform/emr_on_eks/Dockerfile
        - aws_code_base/platform/emr_on_eks/Notebook.Dockerfile
        - aws_code_base/platform/CommonLib/**
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
  tags:
    - dev
    - aws

dev-deploy-emrcustomimage:
  stage: dev-deploy
  script:
    - cd ./aws_code_base/platform/
    - aws ecr get-login-password --region us-west-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 123********.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
    - docker pull 123********.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/spark/emr-6.11.0:latest
    - docker pull 123********.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/notebook-jeg/emr-6.11.0:latest
    - docker pull 123********.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/notebook-spark/emr-6.11.0:latest
    - cp $CI_PROJECT_DIR/aws_code_base/platform/CommonLib/dist/*tar.gz .
    - docker build --no-cache -f ./emr_on_eks/Dockerfile -t emr6.11.0_custom .
    - docker build --no-cache -f ./emr_on_eks/Notebook.Dockerfile -t emr6.11.0_notebook_custom .
    - aws ecr get-login-password --region us-west-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin {account_id}.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
    - docker tag emr6.11.0_custom {account_id}.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/emr6.11.0_custom_repo:dev
    - docker tag emr6.11.0_notebook_custom {account_id}.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/emr6.11.0_custom_repo:notebook_dev
    - docker push {account_id}.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/emr6.11.0_custom_repo:dev
    - docker push {account_id}.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/emr6.11.0_custom_repo:notebook_dev
    - IMAGES_TO_DELETE=$( aws ecr list-images --region us-west-2 --repository-name emr6.11.0_custom_repo --filter "tagStatus=UNTAGGED" --query 'imageIds[*]' --output json )
    - aws ecr batch-delete-image --region us-west-2 --repository-name emr6.11.0_custom_repo --image-ids "$IMAGES_TO_DELETE" || true
    - docker system prune -a -f
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: manual
      allow_failure: false
      changes:
        - aws_code_base/platform/emr_on_eks/Dockerfile
        - aws_code_base/platform/emr_on_eks/Notebook.Dockerfile
        - aws_code_base/platform/CommonLib/**
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
  needs:
    - job: deploy-dev-commonlib
      artifacts: true
  tags:
    - dev
    - aws

dev-deploy-postgres:
  stage: dev-deploy
  script:
    - pip3 install boto3
    - git fetch
    - added_files=$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_SHA | tr '\n' ' ')
    - modified_files=$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_SHA | tr '\n' ' ')
    - renamed_files=$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_SHA | tr '\n' ' ')
    - echo $added_files "," $modified_files "," $renamed_files
    - python3 aws_code_base/platform/deployments/scripts/postgres_deploy.py "$added_files" "$modified_files" "$renamed_files" "aws_code_base/platform/CommonLib/CommonLib/devConfigs.json"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: manual
      allow_failure: false
      changes:
        - 'aws_code_base/platform/postgres/**'
        - 'aws_code_base/dataengineering/**/schema_*.json'
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
  tags:
    - dev
    - aws

dev-deploy-snowflake:
  stage: dev-deploy
  script:
    - pip3 install boto3 snowflake-connector-python --use-feature=2020-resolver
    - git fetch
    - added_files=$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_SHA | tr '\n' ' ')
    - modified_files=$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_SHA | tr '\n' ' ')
    - renamed_files=$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_SHA | tr '\n' ' ')
    - echo $added_files "," $modified_files "," $renamed_files
    - python3 aws_code_base/platform/deployments/scripts/snowflake_deploy.py "$added_files" "$modified_files" "$renamed_files" "aws_code_base/platform/CommonLib/CommonLib/devConfigs.json" "dev"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: manual
      allow_failure: false
      changes:
        - aws_code_base/snowflake/**
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
  tags:
    - dev
    - aws
```

Comment: Hmm. I think the rule looks OK, though you shouldn't need the `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` check to exclude running for MRs because `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` is only present on branch pipelines. If you don't want MR pipelines at all, you should probably do that in `workflow:rules:` instead (as the rules in your other jobs can cause MR pipelines to be created) Do you have an open merge request for that branch? If so, can you double check your project's pipelines page to make sure there aren't two pipelines being created?

Comment: Nope, I do not have a open pull request for the branch that I'm working on. 

I understand if we have an open pull request, the current rule
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
 will prevent it from creating a pipeline. 

I just want the pipeline to be build with dev-deploy stage in it for every commit that is being pushed to the branch except main.

Comment: Hmm. I can't reproduce this behavior on gitlab.com -- when I configure a pipeline with a job using the rules you've shared in your post, the job runs both when the branch is first pushed, and when subsequent changes are pushed. There may be something else other than what you've shared that's causing the unexpected behavior. Can you try creating a complete reproducible example?

Comment: I have attached the complete dev-deploy jobs. 

Those are the all the jobs. 

I'm guessing the `changes` param is not working as expected. Even though there is are no changes to the specific files in the directories mentioned for commonlib and emrcustomimage - the jobs are still running ! And if there are no changes to the files in those directories - i think the pipeline with dev-deploy stage is not being built. Something is not stitching not together here.

Comment: @sytech 
Two main things here: 

1. I should be able to build the pipeline on every commit to the branch with only one stage (dev-deploy) and should be able to run manually if I want to. this should not build a pipeline when there is open MR. 

2. Even if I run manually - the jobs inside the stage dev-deploy should adhere to it's `changes` section. Which means it should only run when it encounters a change in those directories/files.

Comment: By default `changes:` only evaluates changes against the previous available commit before the push event on the same branch. In the case where you first create a branch, there is no other ref against which `changes:` can be evaluated because the branch was only just created. Whenever there is no comparison SHA available, `changes:` will simply be evaluated as true. This would explain why the job runs when you first push to the branch, but not on subsequent pushes (that don't change those files). Keep in mind there are some other limitations with `changes:`, too, such as max number of files.

Comment: @sytech I understood the limitations of `changes: ` but is there a better way to tackle this issue? 

Can we not specify `changes:` to compare with `main` ref instead of previous commits to the branch? Or how can we build the pipeline with dev-deploy stage? 

For ex: If I'm making continues changes on a sql file on different commits - I should be build to run the dev-deploy-snowflake job every time I push. If the pipeline is not getting build on every push then it's make it harder. I'm looking for a way here.

Comment: You can set `changes:compare_to:` to be `main`, yes. That may be what you're wanting to do.

Comment: That doesn't work either. 

I modified the ci to be : 


 rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: manual
      allow_failure: false
      changes:
        paths:
          - aws_code_base/platform/emr_on_eks/Dockerfile
          - aws_code_base/platform/emr_on_eks/Notebook.Dockerfile
          - aws_code_base/platform/CommonLib/**
        compare_to: 'master'
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never

Comment: @sytech
if there is a change in the Dockerfile the dev-deploy stage appears with only two jobs : dev-deploy-common and dev-deploy-emrcustomimage 

In another commit if there is a change in the SQL file I do not see the job 
dev-deploy-snowflake job in the stage. I still only see two jobs in the pipeline. Whereas I need see three jobs.